# Phonegap: Creating Sqlite Database with simple queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am new to Phonegap, I want to craete a Sqlite3 database using JQuery / JavaScript in which I want to know how to create table, how to run queries using this.

Please help me out on that.

Comment: this link must be helpful http://coenraets.org/blog/?s=phonegap

Comment: Your question is overly broad. Have you read the docs at all? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage. From your question it appears as if you have not. Please do so.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below link. i'm sure it'll help you out.

https://github.com/k4ml/halal-android